# Project Error QT

Tags: linux, qt

I m trying to open and run a project but I m getting this issue

Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: declarative
Error while parsing file /home/vegeta/Desktop/10/gui/SBMPO_QT_gui.pro. Giving up.
Cannot read /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++/qmake.conf: No such file or directory
Could not read qmake configuration file /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++/qmake.conf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have not install qtdeclarative library and if you are using QtCreator - check kits

Comment: How to install qtdeclarative library? I installed QtCreator IDE through Ubuntu Software center

Comment: search for qt declarative then in software center . On Kubuntu 14.04 I have this package libqt4-declarative for Qt4 and libqt5declarative5 for Qt5. Looks like you need Qt4 version

Comment: libqt4-declarative  is already installed but I could not find declarative for qt5 .I m running Ubuntu 14.04.1

Comment: Which version of Qt do you wanna use? If Qt4 then check also this packages(qt4-dev-tools, qt4-qmake) are installed

Comment: Note that qt declarative module in Qt5 is called QtQuick1

Comment: Qt 5 Qt Quick 2 is also installed but could not find the solution

Comment: If you wanna use Qt5 then you should run qmake version for Qt5. To do so check that qmake for Qt5 is installed, check that you use Qt5 Kit in QtCreator(Tools -> Options -> Build&Run -> ..) and Projects page